# addFieldToFilter not returning attribute values

Tags: eav, product-collection, collection-filtering, magento-1.7

I have a product attribute called remote_image_link. When I retrieve a product using this code:

```
$mageProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('sku',"1234")->getFirstItem();
```

And then try and get the value of the attribute RemoteImageLink,

```
$mageProduct->getRemoteImageLink()
```

Nothing is returned. But when I add this code:

```
$mageProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($mageProduct->getId());
```

Then it works and I can get a value for the remote_image attribute.

How come I have to call load, aren't I loading using the addFieldToFileter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all use `addAttributeToFilter` instead of `addFieldToFilter`. It's cleaner that way.
And retrieve your product like this:

```
$mageProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('remote_image_link')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku',"1234")->getFirstItem();
```

When getting a collection not all attributes are added to the collection. You need to add manually the attributes you need.
If for some reason that doesn't work, set the attribute `remote_image_link` to be `Used in product listing`.

Comment: so load will pull in everything but a collection won't pull in all attributes. That is confusing from a developers perspective. I would assume both actions would return the same result.

Comment: I know it can be confusing at first, but there is a reason for that. **Performance**. When getting a collection you may not need all the attributes so there is no point in loading all. If you want to load all you can add `->addAttributeToSelect('*')`